# Why is first column in table wider than last column?

Tags: html, html-table

Why is it that the first column in this table is wider than any of the content in its cells. The img in the seconded row is to span 2 columns so if columns 2,3 & 4 were to space evenly (which seems logical) then columns 1 & 2 would be wide enough for the img without having to make column 1 wider than 4. Am I missing the obvious? This is causing havoc with my layout. I know I could maybe use divs but the images and other content in table maybe changed frequently and so tables seem the most logical besides not understanding whats going on is driving me crazy. :)

```
<table border="1"style="top:2px;left:0px;position:absolute">
    <td>DeliDeliDeli</td><td colspan="3">
        <img src="pics/deli.jpg" width="480" height="384" alt="" title="" border="0" />
    </td>
    <td>DeliDeliDeli</td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="Bulk pics/jars3.jpg" width="227" height="170" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
    </td>
    <td>Deli</td>
    <td>Deli</td>
    <td>Deli</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Deli</td>
        <td>Deli</td>
        <td>Deli</td>
        <td>Deli</td>
        <td>Deli</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is *up* with your `<tr>` elements?

Comment: It always works best to start with *valid* markup, which the posted code is not. Different browsers will try to "correct" invalid markup in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 2):

`<table>` tags are more or less free to choose their own size unless you tell them otherwise.

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the table's style, then add this before the first row:

```
<colgroup><col span="5" style="width: 20%" /></colgroup>
```